# Pushing JUnit test report to Xray Jira using Powershell?

Tags: rest, powershell, jira

Pushing JUnit test report to Xray Jira using Powershell ?

I run `SOAPUI` test in my `VSTS` pipeline, and generate a `JUnit` report I want to put to the XRay who is managed by the team.

Following this doc, I wrote a Powershell script in order to make a Rest call to JIRA :

```
$user = 'foooooooo'
$pass = 'foooooooo'
$pair = "$($user):$($pass)"
$encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair))
$basicAuthValue = "Basic $encodedCreds"

try
{
    $res = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'http://foooo.com/rest/raven/1.0/import/execution/junit?projectKey=foooooo' -Headers @{"Authorization" = $basicAuthValue} -ContentType 'multipart/form-data' -Method POST -InFile "C:\fooo\report.xml"

    Write-host $res
}
catch
{
    write-host $_
}
```

I face the following message : The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
The support keeps telling that it must be a Powershell issue related to multipart management.

Comment: I use the Jira cmdlets extensively have you tried them? https://atlassianps.org/